# does anyone know about any places that sell the pawls and spring for a Ringle Demon II that dont charge £15 shipping?

Tags: parts

I've scoured the internet trying to find a webiste or place that sell the pawls and spring for my Sun Ringle Demon II, that dont charge £15-£20 shipping like Ebay and Bike discounts (websites)

Comment: Last item I shipped was from Wisconsin to NZ, $48 USD for a $20 part.  And its been 6 weeks in transit via Japan, and counting.   Shipping is very expensive now due to a combination of C19 circumstances and cost increases.  Suck it up - we all are.   Or, if you're mechanically minded, make your own pawls from stock metal.

Comment: (Assuming £=UK) This is a recent trend where UK supply has been hammered by huge demand, making items hard to find, so you're more likely to find an item from a European stockist, but most European sellers now add significant postal charges because Brexit has increased their costs (who knew). Also, deliveries can be slower than normal from abroad rn. You could combine the two existing answers by asking the distributor which is your local stockist, who could order you the part. Distributors typically send things out very quickly, so you might get it cheapest and quickest by doing this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Ask the distributor.

https://www.hotlines-uk.com/contactus

00000000

Answer (score 1):

If you visit all the bike shop in the area (+-20 mi), you will find one that carries the required items.

But how much do you value your time :D ?